# Ms SQL 2005 : Select a ID for a particular date where that date lies between fromdate and Todate

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have two tables called table A , Table B 
In table A there are fromdate and Todate columns  which are dates of employees
In table B there are f1date , T1date , empID 
The table A fromdate should be between f1date and T1date from table B  , so whenever the fromdate lies in table B between f1date and t1date  i want to get that ID in ms SQL 2005

I tried but it's not working out ,  i want you guys help to fix this ...

Comment: could you please add the query you had so far and see what we can find in your query. It always helpful to add code to start with

Comment: How is date stored in table, smalldatetime ?

Comment: Can you tell me what ties table A to table B??

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @vfromdate datetime
Declare @vTodate datetime 
Declare @vF1date datetime
Declare @vT1date datetime 
Declare @vEMPID nvarchar(10)
```

Select @vEmpId from table B where @vfromdate  between F1date and T1date

Print @vEmpId

This is the query i have written but something went wrong

I want to select EmpId's from table B  whenever the fromdate  from table A lies between  f1date and f2date  i should get that EMPID